# ssh2_connect define explicit TLS

Tags: php, ftp, ssh2-sftp

Trying to connect to remote sftp using the following code:

```
    if( ! function_exists('ssh2_connect') ){
        die( 'Missing ssh2_connect' );
    }

    $callbacks = array(
        'disconnect' => function( $reason, $message, $language ){

            printf("Server disconnected with reason code [%d] and message: %s\n",
           $reason, $message);

        },
        'debug' => array( $this , function( $message, $language, $always_display ){

            printf("%s %s %s\n",$message,$language,$always_display);

        }, )
    );

    $connection = ssh2_connect( $this->ftp_ip , $this->ftp_port , array() , $callbacks ) or die("Connection failed:");

    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $this->ftp_user , $this->ftp_pass );

    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

THe result that i get is "Connection failed"

The remote sftp server requires Explicit FTP over TLS (this is how I use filezilla to connect - and the connection is working)

How can i define Explicit FTP over TLS using ssh2_connect ?

**EDIT**
Tried also connecting with ftp_ssl_connect

```
$connection = ftp_ssl_connect( $this->ftp_ip , $this->ftp_port ) or die("Connection failed:");
```

Same result here: "Connection failed"

Answer (score 0):

`ssh2_connect` (and other `ssh2_*` functions) is for SSH and SFTP.

Explicit FTP over TLS is a completely different protocol. For that use [`ftp_ssl_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) and other `ftp_*` functions.

Comment: Forgot to mention that i have tried it as well $connection = ftp_ssl_connect( $this->ftp_ip , $this->ftp_port ) or die("Connection failed:"); - it returned connection failed

Comment: What is the value of `ftp_ip` and `ftp_port`? Can you also post a FileZilla log file? Are you running FileZilla on the same machine as your PHP code?